# Email formating using System.Net.Mail smtpclient

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I format the body of the email so it doesn't look so old school :)
I've tried sending html through it, but it just comes out as html in the body of the email.

Thanks for any help and assistance, cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the [`IsBodyHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx) property to true.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx

Comment: Beat me to it because I went looking for the link, but +1 to you.

Comment: IC, this should give me a start. I was just using smtpclient.send(to,from,subject,body) So, now can I just use MailMessage?

Comment: Yes, create an instance of MailMessage then send it using smtpClient.Send()

Answer (score 0):

Including the above, I use StringBuilder's to format the contents of my emails like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("{0} submitted the following information from the site:", txtName.Text);
```

I just find it's helpful in visualizing the outcome rather than doing +='s and such.